# SQL number checking trigger

Tags: sql, error-handling, triggers

I need ID to be an eight whole digit number.

```
create table foo(
ID  primary key DEFERRABLE,
);

create or replace trigger foo_trg 
before insert or update
on foo
for each row
Begin
  if :new.ID > 99999999  or :new.ID < 9999999 then 
    raise pkg.Illegal_update;
  end if;
end;
/
```

Right now my trigger can only stop an illegal update if the number is too large or too small.  I need a way of checking for a decimal in a number

Any suggestions are welcome thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the DBMS? I'd declare the type of the id column to be an integer. In Oracle, you'd do it like this:

```
create table foo(
ID  NUMBER(8,0) primary key DEFERRABLE,
);
```

Is there some reason this is made deferrable?

Comment: it has to do with the way i am loading my data in, but it get confusing... thank you I can't believe I did not think of that haha

Answer (score 0):

You can use `floor(number) = number` if all else fails.